# Same named group multiple times in JVM?

Tags: java, regex, groovy

Is there a way in JVM (preferably in Java or a small library) to have the following regex `(?<Hour>\\d\\d)*` and to be able to extract all the hours? For example if "12131415" is given then to be able to get a collections of hours something like {12,13,14,15}.

Does groovy support this?

Comment: *Is there a way in JVM*  - What has JVM gotto do with this? :P

Comment: This can be done in .Net, and I was not able to do this using java and I didn't found a lib that is able to help. So I need a solution for java. I said JVM because if there is no lib maybe this can be done in Groovy or other programing language that works in JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would capture each two digits and stores it into separate groups.

Your code would be,

```
String s = "12131415";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<Hour>\\d{2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/QebIf6)

Comment: Thanks, your example works, but actually my expression is more complex. It has some named groups that are optional, some that repeats 0..n, and some that are found in multiple places in the expression. So I can't apply your solution in my case. I am looking for a solution more like  ...getGroups("Hour") that return  a collection.

Comment: As it is impossible in java to get all the named groups that mach a given name, and I didn't find any library to support this I will accept your solution. In my case I split the regular expression in smaller ones and I parse the string with find (as you suggested) for each expresion.